# Moving columns from the back of a file to the front

Tags: sorting, awk

I have a file with a very large number of columns (basically several thousand sets of threes) with three special columns (`Chr` and `Position` and `Name`) at the end.

I want to move these final three columns to the front of the file, so that that columns become `Name Chr Position` and then the file continues with the trios.

I think this might be possible with `awk`, but I don't know enough about how `awk` works to do it!

Sample input:

```
Gene1.GType Gene1.X    Gene1.Y ....ending in GeneN.Y     Chr     Position        Name
```

Desired Output:

```
Name    Chr     Position        (Gene1.GType Gene1.X     Gene1.Y ) x n samples
```

Comment: Please supply some sample input and output, it's not quite clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for making this more easily read, Birei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below example does more or less what you want.

```
$ cat file
A B C D E F G Chr Position Name
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ cat process.awk 
{
  printf $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF
  for( i=1; i<NF-2; i++)
  {
   printf " "$i
  }
  print " "
}
$ awk -f process.awk file 
Chr Position Name A B C D E F G 
8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

`NF` in `awk` denotes the number of field on a row.

Comment: The order of its fields in output is different, and would be better to use `OFS` instead repeat the space character so many times, but it works, so **+1**

Comment: @Birei This is a good point, but couldn't find it working with `printf $i,`. How would one go about that?

Comment: Didn't work for me, but that was probably something to do with the huge file. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

one liner:

```
awk '{ Chr=$(NF-2) ; Position=$(NF-1) ; Name=$NF ; $(NF-2)=$(NF-1)=$NF="" ; print Name, Chr, Position, $0 }' file
```